# prevent gnome-keyring from storing vpn password

Tags: linux, vpn, passwords

gnome keyring keeps helpfully storing the password to my vpn link. That link uses two factor and so the password changes each time, causing the connection to fail.

Does network manager have a setting to avoid it storing a password on a vpn link ? If i remove the password using seahorse it does ask one time, but it's an annoying workaround.

This is on fedora 23, NetworkManager-1.0.10-3.fc23.x86_64

Answer (score 4):

gah ! dumbest thing ever !

I'll post this here incase anyone else runs into this.

The solution is simple, at the end of the password entry field there's a little logo. Clicking that gives you the option to ask for the password everytime. Not obvious, but easy once you know !

Comment: omg ... thanks! that UX hasn't improved in 6 years :/